# Retrofit response to POJO

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm working with a endpoint that returns data exactly like this.

```
[
   {
     "CodigoParada":4201929,
     "Nome":"",
     "Endereco":"RUA JOAO DE LIMA BONFANTE (B-C)",
     "Latitude":-23.687475,
     "Longitude":-46.771474
   },
   {
     "CodigoParada":640000453,
     "Nome":"ACANGAPIRANGA C/B",
     "Endereco":" R CONSTANTINO NERY/ AV BENEDITO ANDRADE ",
     "Latitude":-23.485653,
     "Longitude":-46.71567
   }
]
```

I'm trying to use Retrofit to request the data and parse it into a POJO like this:

```
public class Parada {

    private int codigoParada;
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;

    public int getCodigoParada() {
        return codigoParada;
    }

    public void setCodigoParada(int codigoParada) {
        this.codigoParada = codigoParada;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Retrofit pulls the data back correctly. I can see it in my logs.
However, it seems to have trouble parsing it into my "Parada" model.

This is my request:

```
@GET("/Parada/Buscar?termosBusca=*")
public void getAllStops(Callback<List<Parada>> cb);
```

I'm sure its something small. Just can't spot it.

**UPDATE**

Including my restAdapter.

```
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setEndpoint(myEndpoint)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new GsonBuilder().create())).build();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Gson annotation @SerializedName() to map attribute name to java member.

e.g:

```
@SerializedName("Latitude")
String latitude;

@SerializedName("Longitude")
String longitude;
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I didn't realize it was case sensitive. A note for others, I had to do it to all fields.

Answer (score 2):

I know you marked the previous answer as correct. But just in case someone else read this. you can convert any JSON to the appropiate POJO using this page. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ it works great

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Link to create Responce to pojo in Retrofit Api**

```
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
```

[image]

```
-----------------------------------com.example.YourClassName.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class YourClassName {

@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private Integer id;
@SerializedName("isImportant")
@Expose
private Boolean isImportant;
@SerializedName("picture")
@Expose
private String picture;
@SerializedName("from")
@Expose
private String from;
@SerializedName("subject")
@Expose
private String subject;
@SerializedName("message")
@Expose
private String message;
@SerializedName("timestamp")
@Expose
private String timestamp;
@SerializedName("isRead")
@Expose
private Boolean isRead;

public Integer getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
this.id = id;
}

public Boolean getIsImportant() {
return isImportant;
}

public void setIsImportant(Boolean isImportant) {
this.isImportant = isImportant;
}

public String getPicture() {
return picture;
}

public void setPicture(String picture) {
this.picture = picture;
}

public String getFrom() {
return from;
}

public void setFrom(String from) {
this.from = from;
}

public String getSubject() {
return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
this.subject = subject;
}

public String getMessage() {
return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
this.message = message;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
return timestamp;
}

public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
this.timestamp = timestamp;
}

public Boolean getIsRead() {
return isRead;
}

public void setIsRead(Boolean isRead) {
this.isRead = isRead;
}

}
```